# Python frustrated install library won't install

Tags: python, installation, beautifulsoup

I am on Windows XP.

I have downloaded Python 2.7 as per the recommendations here.  I clicked the .msi link and it installed fine.  Now, I want to use beautifulsoup.  I have downloaded version 3.2.0.

I have no idea where to put it or how to install it.  I put it into a c:\temp folder and double clicked on setup.py and it does something but my test file does not work.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print soup.prettify()
```

What am I doing wrong?
I tried to install using the command line too as it said, but that just gives more errors about python not being recognised.  Normal python script works fine.  Just I have no idea what to do with this library to install it.  Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't double click on setup.py . Open command and then navigate to the folder where setup.py is. Then run:

```
python setup.py install
```

After that, try `import BeautifulSoup`. If it works, all is well.

Comment: I tried that, it gives me errors about path not found.  I don't want to mess too much with the system.  Python was supposed to be easy!  Is it possible to do the install manually?  Can I just copy the 2 main looking files somewhere?  Can you tell me where to put them?

Comment: Yes, it is possible you get path not found. To get around this, navigate to the folder where Python is installed (C:\Python<version> most probably) and then try out the above step, giving the full path to setup.py

Comment: I am reading the dos box, it says for each module that the module was not found.  
I entered:
python c:\temp\BeautifulSoup-3.2.0\setup.py install

I guess because it at least tried to install modules that I got the python location correct?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Python is not about programming complexity, but distribution complexity.
Better if you use a better distribution, such as ActivePython (uninstall current one and install this one):

http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads

The difference between this distribution and the official one is that this modifies the PATH environment variable, so the Python executable will be reachable, and your:

`python setup.py install`

... will work, wherever you are.

Another possibility, of course, is to manually modify your PATH variable to include the bin directory of your Python distribution. This is explained here:

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: I'd rather go with the official distribution. It's super easy to modify your path to make python.exe accessible.

Comment: Well, the problem is that is not so easy for non-technical people. That kind of distributions makes it easier for these people to have their systems up and running. Also, I can tell that I'm using ActivePython and haven't had any (compatibility or whatever) problem.

Comment: If you're doing development, it's most likely that you're a technical person. I don't think a "non-technical" person would be going out of there way to use python or ask questions like this on SO. Compared to writing programs, altering your PATH variable is cake. I haven't tried ActivePython myself so I can't say much about it, I usually use official and stable releases. I'll check out ActivePython some time, what is the benefit over the official python releases?

Comment: Thanks I am downloading this now.  Will try it.  I just want to program.  I hate having to waste 3 hours just to get every programming language setup.  Why can't it be easy?!

Comment: > "If you're doing development, it's most likely that you're a  technical person. I don't think a "non-technical" person would be going out of there way to use python" I don't think I get your point: Why are we commenting on this question, after all? My point is not that ActivePython is a better python. It just make it easier to use Official Python. I am a technical person myself, and I still use ActivePython because I don't like the mess of dealing with all this installation subtle issues: I have a lot more better things to do.

Comment: @David19801, well, the operating system in which is easier to install Python is Linux... :-D